# Responsibility of disclosing potential social engineering attack

Tags: social-engineering, banks, sms

I've just gotten a text message from a number pretending to be my bank and telling me to install a certificate from a suspicious link (link looks like this: bankname-certificate.ru/installation not the actual link obviously)

I have some non-tech aware people in my social circles so I alerted them and instructed them not to use the link etc...

Should I alert my bank about this message? and if yes, how should I do this?

Comment: I would contact your bank and ask to speak their fraud team.

Comment: @iain Thanks, I've contacted them and they asked me to send screenshots as an attachment to an email. I'll update this if they get back to me!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, contact your bank and let them know. I would firstly lookup the fraud department for your institution an send them an email, or call them, and tell them explicitly what you received.

You can run the link URL through [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/) to see if there are any red flags that pop as well. This will give you more information to pass on to the fraud team.